# Laravel How to insert data to 2 tables which has foreign key to each other

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables: **stocks**, **colors** and **images**;

**colors** has a foreign key on **stocks**

and **images** has a foreign key on **colors**
 like this

Stocks:

```
id    | name     
-------------------------
1     | Berlin - Paris 
2     | Madrid - London
3     | Berlin - Paris
```

Colors:

```
id    | stocks_id | icon
---------------------------------------
1     |     1     | img1.png  
2     |     2     | img2.png  
3     |     3     | img3.png
```

Images:

```
id    |  color_id | url
---------------------------------------
1     |     1     | img1.png  
2     |     2     | img2.png  
3     |     3     | img3.png
```

I'm using a *Model* to insert the stocks to the database and *attach()* to create the color with the *belongsTo* relationship.

**How to insert the images using attach() with a foreign key to colors ???**

I've tried many things with *attach()* but I've stuck with it for 2 months

the code I'm using:

```
$stock= new Stocks();
    $stock->storeColors()->attach($request->color_name, array('icon' => request('icon')));
//the line I need to write:
    $stock->storeColors()->storeImages()->attach($request->image);
```

Comment: Please can you show the code you're using.

Comment: @Rwd I did ....

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
$imagenes=[];

$stock= new Stocks();
  $data =  $stock->storeColors()->attach($request->color_name, array('icon' => request('icon')));


  $color = Color::where('stock_id',$data->id)->first();

  if ($request->hasFile('imagen')) {

          foreach ($request->imagen as $image) {

                 $imagenes[]=
                      new Images([
                         'url' => $image->url
                      ]);

      $request->file('imagen')->move('imagenes/','imagenName.jpg');

   }

 }

$color ->images()->saveMany($imagenes);
```

Comment: yes but how can I find and store the **color_id** to the image foreign key column?

Comment: if you store it like that it will automaticaly save the color_id to the images table.

Comment: the point is, I have many images for each color
and I don't know how to get it from the HTML like an array and how to store it

Comment: ok so you want to know how to store multiple image? not only the name you want to upload the image to the server?